# How to reverse the ordering of list items in an unordered list

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an unordered list, like this:

```
<ul id="birds">
  <li>Bald Eagle</li>
  <li>Falcon</li>
  <li>Condor</li>
  <li>Albatross</li>
  <li>Parrot</li>
</ul>
```

With plain JavaScript (not including jQuery), I would like to be able to do reverse the order of this list - so that it matches the following expected "output":

```
<ul id="birds">
  <li>Parrot</li>
  <li>Albatross</li>
  <li>Condor</li>
  <li>Falcon</li>
  <li>Bald Eagle</li>
</ul>
```

This is the JavaScript I have attempted to code, to try and achieve this goal:

```
var birdList = document.getElementById("birds").getElementsByTagName("li");
var birdListReverse = birdList.reverse();

for(var i = 0; i < birdList.length; i++)
{
  birdList[i] = birdListReverse[i];
}
```

I would think that somehow over-writing the current list items with the ones in the "reversed" list would be sufficient, but not to be. Would I have to somehow manipulate each `nodeValue` in the list?

I would like to do this when a button is clicked - that is the easy part, it is just getting the technique to reverse the list that has hampered me a bit.

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the current list items with the reversed ones?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An HTMLCollection is only a read-only view of nodes. In order to manipulate nodes, you have to use one of the various DOM manipulation methods. In your case, there happens to be a shortcut; all you need do is to append the child nodes in reverse order.

```
var birds = document.getElementById("birds");
var i = birds.childNodes.length;
while (i--)
  birds.appendChild(birds.childNodes[i]);
```

**Edit**: What's happening is that `appendChild` removes the node from the document before appending it. This has two effects: a) it saves you from having to make a copy of the list of nodes and removing them before appending them in reverse order, and b) it reverses the order of nodes as it goes, since it appends the last child first and the first child list.

Comment: While the other answers worked for me, this one was the shortest and easiest to code (and worked). Thanks for the advice :). I have tried to "summarise" my understanding of this in my code, with this comment:

"So working backwards from the end of the list and appending each item on the list, in reverse, gives the illusion that each value in the list is "over-written" by it's ordered "opposite" in the list (e.g from a list of 5 items, item 1 becomes item 5, item 2 becomes item 4, item 3 stays the same, item 4 becomes item 2, item 5 becomes item 1)."

Comment: This works because [node.appendChild(newChild)](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) "Adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this node. If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed.". Even [node.insertBefore(newChild,refChild)](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) first removes the newChild if it already is in the tree.

Comment: If there is a lot of nodes, it could (depending on browser) be a [little bit faster](http://jsperf.com/reverse-node-content) to use a document fragment as a temporary storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (in plain javascript).  You can just cycle through the `li` tags in reverse order and append them to the parent.  This will have the natural effect of reversing their order.  You get the last one, append it to the end of the list, get the 2nd to last one, append it to the list.  Get the 3rd to last one, append it to the end of the list and so on and all the items end up reversed.  Note, you can use appendChild on something that is already in the DOM and it will be moved from it's current location automatically (e.g. removed before appended).

```
var birds = document.getElementById("birds");
var birdList = birds.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = birdList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    birds.appendChild(birdList[i]);
}​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GLvxV/

Answer (score 1):

```
var birds = document.getElementById('birds');

for(var i = 0, bll = birds.childNodes.length; i < bll; i++) {
  birds.insertBefore(birds.childNodes[i], birds.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: If you are referring to Neil's use of childNodes, yes, I did revise my answer as the history will show to provide a more concise alternative for the poster. But I did not change my original fundamental approach which was to use `insertBefore`.

Comment: @BrettZamir I think `canon` meant that the answer provided by him/her after some editing ended up being the same as yours, and while noticing so, `canon`choosed to remove his/hers answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const list = document.querySelector("ul");
Array.from(list.children).reverse().forEach(element =>list.appendChild(element));
```

Comment: Won't this duplicate the list elements?

Comment: @vekerdyb no, it doesn't duplicate the list elements. This works.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the `birdList` doesn't re-order the elements because `birdList` is just a collection - a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) - which is independent of the DOM itself.

You actually need to get a reference to the `<ul id="birds">` element and then use a combination of [`removeChild(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild) and [`appendChild(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) - maybe [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("birds");
var birdList = parent.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i = birdList.length-1; i > 0; --i) {
    parent.appendChild(birdList[i];
}
```

Comment: This was very similar to one of my attempts, except that by looking at this, having parent.appendChild and parent.removeChild in consecutive statements makes me think that they somehow cancel each other out. When I test this code fragment, I am only left with one of the list items - the "last" item in the original list.

Comment: You don't need to remove the child because that happens automatically when you append/insert the node. (A node can only be at one point in the tree). If you want to manually remove the child, you must do so before you append/insert it. Documentation for [node.appendChild(newChild)](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) "Adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this node. If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed."

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no need for JavaScript. If you were to use the semantically correct `<ol>` (ordered list) element here (since ordering does obviously matter to you), then you can use the `reversed` attribute to do the exact same thing without any script-dependencies! To reverse the order of the items visually, we'd sprinkle in two lines of CSS with `flex-direction`:

```css
ol[reversed] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<ol reversed>
  <li>Bald Eagle</li>
  <li>Falcon</li>
  <li>Condor</li>
  <li>Albatross</li>
  <li>Parrot</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This simply renumbers the list items; it doesn't actually move the list item elements to a reversed order, which is what was requested.

Comment: @CodeBiker thanks for noticing. Updated my answer with `flex-direction`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this. It works as follows:

- Grab all the bird list items (the `<li>` elements) and return them as a NodeList
- Convert the NodeList into an an array and reverse the array (since items in arrays can be reversed, but not items in NodeLists)
- Append each bird list item from the array into the original list container (the `<ul>` element)

Code:

```
const birdsContainer = document.getElementById("birds");
const birdList = birds.getElementsByTagName("li");

[].slice.call(birdList)
  .reverse()
  .forEach(bird => birdsContainer.appendChild(bird));
```