# Reading a file line by line backwards

Tags: javascript, file-io

How can I read and print out a plain text file on my server line by line in reverse using javascript? I would prefer to use javascript or jquery over php but have no idea how to accomplish something like this. So for instance if I had a file like

```
foo
bar
foobar
barfoo
```

I would like it to print out

```
barfoo
foobar
bar
foo
```

Comment: Is the file on the server? Is it chosen by the file input? Is it plain text? You need to give more details.

Comment: This may have been answered before.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539361/how-to-reverse-the-ordering-of-list-items-in-an-unordered-list][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539361/how-to-reverse-the-ordering-of-list-items-in-an-unordered-list

Comment: @epascarello Yeah the file is on my server, its plain text, its not chosen by file input and I have all the necessary permissons.

Comment: With php - you can do this, literally, with few lines of code...

Comment: @Rentsy The post on that thread by jfriend00 is very close to what I need although I lack the background knowledge of javascript to make it work the way I need it to.

Comment: I wanted to use javascript so I didn't need to change the extension of almost every file on my server that isn't already to a .php file. Also my host doesn't allow me to easily add php support to .html files.

Comment: @josh, as you said - load() file, make array (if entries are separated by new line - shouldn't be too hard), and reverse array: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp

Comment: @Rentsy this is *not* a duplicate, of those questions that you linked at least, because it is reversing contents of a plain text file, not of DOM elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a http-Request:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
   var xmlHttp = null;

   xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
   xmlHttp.send( null );
   return xmlHttp.responseText;
}


var content = httpGet("google.de"); //enter the Url of your text file here
var lines = content.split("\n");
var result = "";

for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
    result = lines[i] + "\n" + result;
alert(result);
```

Demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FB3Mj/) (displaying the source of http://google.de backwards)

Comment: I was here looking for something else but the way you have solved current thread, I got solution to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it using the [FileReader API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/). I am not sure if its still  in draft or not, but it works in Chrome as well as Firefox.

You will have to simply read the file as text using `readAsText` method. And then `split()` the string based on `\n` and then `reverse()` and `join()` again.

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/shobhitg/j7rXu/).

Comment: Well, I misread that 'file on server' part. But really, negative votes for trying to help?