# Reverse <ul> ordering using CSS 2.1

Tags: html, css

I’m attempting to reverse the order of an unordered list using only CSS 2.1

The desired ordering is:
Introduction – History – National Flags – Maritime signal flags

I have previously solved this using CSS rotations however this will not longer be CSS 2.1 compatible.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNEERR?editors=1100

Comment: Only CSS? It maybe [implemented with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539361)

Comment: Why do you want only CSS 2.1?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included sample HTML with desired output and actual output so that people can test their answers.

Comment: @Wowsk The target browser is IE8 which requires this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `inline-block` instead of `float`:

```
#Header #Navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #5D2C2C;
  text-align: right;
}

#Header #Navigation li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

That way the order would not be reversed.

Answer (score 3):

A neat trick is to set the parent `ul` to a flex box and then use the property `flex-direction: column-reverse;`

```
ul{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Comment: Flexbox is not CSS 2.1.

Comment: Is flexbox CSS 3 then?

Comment: Yes, it is. Though admittedly the OP's requirement that a solution be in CSS 2.1 only seems a little contrived, but perhaps they're targeting browsers that strictly focus on CSS 2.1, such as IE8.

Comment: they might also want something that will work on a massive amount of browsers, maybe a public service website, or they might be targeting Opera mini in a low tech country

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code. It works as I just tested on codepen:

```
#Header #Navigation ul { display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse; }

#Header #Navigation li.intro { order: 4; }
#Header #Navigation li.history { order: 2; }
#Header #Navigation li.national { order: 1; }
#Header #Navigation li.inter { order: 3; }
```

I'm not sure if that suits your needs of keeping CSS 2.1 though